# Restful Webservice Using POST

Tags: web-services, rest, post

I am trying to write a rest webservice which uses POST method. I am using Firefox's poster plug-in to test the service. However I am clueless as to how to retrieve whatever I send in the request. Analogous to queryparam in GET can someone tell me how to get params in POST

```
 @Path("/ldap")
       public class Ldap {
String xml = "";
static String ATTRIBUTE_FOR_USER = "sAMAccountName";

@POST
@Path("/xml")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String geterrorxml(@PathParam ("username")@DefaultValue("tess") String                      username,@PathParam ("password")@DefaultValue("passw3") String password) throws Exception {
    MYpojo mYpojo = new MYpojo();

    String xml_output = "";
     System.out.println(username);
      System.out.println(password);
                return null;

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @FormParam and name your inputs etc with the same name as the param

```
<input type="text" name="username" />

public String geterrorxml(@FormParam ("username") @DefaultValue("tess") String username)[..]
```

Comment: no see i dont have a html form, i am going to take the username & password from an action class(such is the requirement) from that action class i'll set up a http connection and send userdetails as params

Comment: It´s the same principle, you just use an API to post something with your code instead of html and a browser. I read your questions as you are testing post and having problems getting the web-service to work.

Comment: yes can you elaborate a bit more on using an API to post something with your code instead of html and a browser. An yes i made the servcie but i am not able to get it to work

Comment: This explains how you can use the Jersey Client libraries to create a post. http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html#crud_client.

I'm assuming you are using java for your client

Comment: thanks a lot!!! it worked, i created a form object with help of jersey apis and posted two fileds to the service which it picked up using formparam, now my problem is that i actually have to send 10 params to the service, so is it possible to change the call and retrieval in such a way that 10 params go at once say like an array of strings, and retrieve an whole array(how will formparam react to form param array)

Comment: Thanks man but i used nornal JSON only to get it done, even LDAP authentication code works fine.... my last and final problem is to get the Httpsession id from the webservice....any idea as to how it can be done????